# Perl: How to process HTTP response with encode_base64

Tags: perl, base64

1. I have an task to generate an BASE64 string from HTTP response which will be used by the external program.Before I was doing this,I had known that if you use BASE64,the length of the string will be extend like 57 * 4/3 = 76.
2. But I've no idea which need to be handle if the HTTP respone longer than 57 bytes! So I had not any special handle for the HTTP response,just direct covert "$response->content" to which I want.(Actually length of the response more than 57 bytes).

3.The unexpected thing is that the length of the encode string not excatly follow 4/3 rule!!! When the len of input string is 57,then len of encode string is 77. When the len of input string is 114, the encode string is 154,why?

4.When I try to use the BASE64 output from an external c# arg(),seems it can only receive first 57 bytes.

```
#Sample Code
my $cont = $response->content;
$cont = substr ($cont, 0, 57);
my $encode = encode_base64($cont);
printf("Length Before Decode = %d.\n",length($cont));
printf("Length After Decode = %d.\n",length($encode));
#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this note](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/articles/perl/perl-base64/), `encode_base64()` adds a newline.  Are you counting that newline in the encoded string length?  It seems to account for your extra character.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response! But is it an normal thing that it will generate a extra byte? In deed I want to print the HTTP response as BASE 64 then my external C# program can receive it as an Arg(), then to do the next step, is it any consideration should be do?

Comment: If the extra byte is indeed just a newline, then you ought to be safe `chomp`ing it off.  One other thing to look into is whether the Base64 decode in C# matches the exact Base64 encode Perl offers.  The Wikipedia page for Base64 lists several variants:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Sorry to disturb again.But after I use "chomp($encode)" ,seems it only can affect one line, for example,if length of $encode is 57,it is ok,length of chomp($encode) is 76,but when length of $encode exceed 57 ,it only remove first added line.

Comment: @Mr.ke:  I'm not sure I understand.  If `encode_base64` only adds a single extra newline on its result, then `chomp` would remove it.

Comment: The unexpected thing which I met is that it is not only one byte extra added,if the original string is 114,then two bytes more,if original string is 570,then ten bytes more.

Comment: Aha... The `encode_base64()` function adds line breaks every 76 characters.  I didn't realize that.  After some additional research, I see there's a `encode_base64url` which does not add these line breaks:  http://perldoc.perl.org/MIME/Base64.html

Comment: Really benefit from your comments. Although I can not call the "encode_base64url" in my case and I've no idea what'wrong.Finally I found I can achieve my ppurpose As below(add an null EOL).                               my $encode = encode_base64($cont,'');